# Virtual Box won't allow me to enter base memory

Tags: 15.04, virtualbox, windows-xp, virtualbox-networking

I'm trying to install virtual box in my Ubuntu 15.04 machine. I specifically want to use Windows XP for some project. I used

```
sudo apt-get install virtual box
```

to install Virtual Box. After that I did this:

1. Selected Windows architecture and Windows XP 64-Bit as OS. Entered Name as Windows XP
2. Now when I'm given the option to enter base memory. Virtual box won't let me move forward. here is the image of what is happening:

   [image]

can someone please help?

Comment: Well the issue looks like the slider's messed up: 0 should be on the left with the larger number on the right. Are you able to type in the box?

Comment: I'm able to type in the box only once. But NEXT would still be grayed out.

Comment: Apart from that, slider won't move at all

Answer (score 0):

If you look in `/home/<user>/VirtualBox VMs/<path to VM>`
Look for `<VM>.vbox` and edit this file
Look for the Memory line and modify this carefully.
Run the emulator an check the memory

Answer (score 0):

Your window looks very weird. Window Border looks like from Ambiance, but rest like from broken Redmond or like you've run it on WINE... Maybe try different theme? Or maybe your system is missing something required for this theme to work properly... Don't know what you have for changing themes, some tools can give clues in case you need to install additional libraries.

You can also try installing VirtualBox using latest version from it's website:
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

You can install it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.0_5.0.18-106667~Ubuntu~wily_amd64.deb
```

Or even better do it with "Software Center" or "GDebi" (dpkg might not work properly in some cases).